# Angular displays url encoded errors, how to get decoded version?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I have uncaught errors in my angular applications the console message looks like this:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DENVIRONMENT%0AJ%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A11%3A416%0Aeb%2Fr.%24injector%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A45%3A375%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A43%3A364%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Fapp%2Fapp.js%3A42%3A18%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A44%3A154%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A42%3A320%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A42%3A452%0Am%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A12%3A320%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A42%3A229%0Aeb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A45%3A1%0AAc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A24%3A339%0AAc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A25%3A151%0AZd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A23%3A464%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A294%3A428%0An.Callbacks%2Fj%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A2%3A26920%0An.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A2%3A27738%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A2%3A29530%0AI%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2Flibs.js%3A2%3A29721%0AnrWrapper%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8600%2F%23%2Fdashboard%3A15%3A12749%0A
```

Which is not useful, but if I url_decode it it is much better, like this:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=ENVIRONMENT
J/<@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:11:416
eb/r.$injector<@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:45:375
d@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:43:364
@http://localhost:8600/app/app.js:42:18
e@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:44:154
d@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:42:320
g/<@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:42:452
m@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:12:320
g@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:42:229
eb@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:45:1
Ac/d@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:24:339
Ac@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:25:151
Zd@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:23:464
@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:294:428
n.Callbacks/j@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:2:26920
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:2:27738
.ready@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:2:29530
I@http://localhost:8600/libs.js:2:29721
nrWrapper@http://localhost:8600/#/dashboard:15:12749
```

How can I get angular to output errors this way by default? Thanks.

Comment: There is a website that can decode them for you: https://matts-apps.net/angularjs-error-decoder/

Answer (score 6):

It's url encoded because it's a link. Click it! :D

It will bring you to a webpage that explains the error.

[This is your error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DENVIRONMENT%0AJ%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:11:416%0Aeb%2Fr.$injector%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:45:375%0Ad@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:43:364%0A@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Fapp%2Fapp.js:42:18%0Ae@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:44:154%0Ad@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:42:320%0Ag%2F%3C@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:42:452%0Am@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:12:320%0Ag@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:42:229%0Aeb@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:45:1%0AAc%2Fd@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:24:339%0AAc@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:25:151%0AZd@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:23:464%0A@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:294:428%0An.Callbacks%2Fj@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:2:26920%0An.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:2:27738%0A.ready@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:2:29530%0AI@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2Flibs.js:2:29721%0AnrWrapper@http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8600%2F%23%2Fdashboard:15:12749%0A)

If you go to that page and look at the error it will say that it threw an error because of x error. Then [that error will be a link to](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=ENVIRONMENT), so click that as well.

And now that you've gotten to that last page, the error is that you have an unknown provider called ENVIRONMENT.

Comment: Hm, it seems firebug does not let me click the links so still annoying. That's pretty cool though, thanks.

Comment: Oh, well that sucks :/ Use chrome to develop, then test later with FF? Good luck! :)

Comment: This is not an answer.  The question is how to disable this stupid link-to-error functionality.  It might be useful when you're a newbie, but eventually you know what the different error types are and just want to see the details without hunting through urlencoded data.

Comment: Well the question was how to url decode the url to gleem the data from it, which you can interpret as "How do I interpret this url to get error information." The answer to which is just click the link, which is the answer I gave. If you want to display errors directly in the console then you should override the default error handler like Maxim Goncharuk describes below.

Answer (score 3):

You can override exception handler:

```
angular.module('exceptionOverride', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
  return function(exception, cause) {
    exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
    throw exception;
  };
});
```

[More here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler)